# NFS export sporadic slow

Tags: nfs, network-share

nfs server exporting to between 300-400 clients. Say client A and B is copying the same file simultaneously from the nfs server. ClientA will be doing 100mb/s and the clientB would be doing 1-2mb/s. Then one day later, the speed problem would reverse. Client A drops to 1-2mb/s. I'm sure the client bandwidth isn't being saturated. When it is doing 1-2/mbs, I struggle to even do a simple *ls* or *cd*.  During the slow transfer rate, there is nothing in dmesg or /var/log/messages.

The eth0 RX packet dropped rate is on a steady increase on the server.

NFS server:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
    inet x.x.x.x  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast x.x.x.x
    inet6 fe80::225:b5ff:feff:b000  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:25:b5:ff:b0:00  txqueuelen 10000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 943628558144  bytes 616933252471494 (561.0 TiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 760517201  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 294979961515  bytes 920493526252565 (837.1 TiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


ethtool -S eth0
 NIC statistics:
 tx_frames_ok: 295630824296
 tx_unicast_frames_ok: 295630824219
 tx_multicast_frames_ok: 10
 tx_broadcast_frames_ok: 67
 tx_bytes_ok: 921153721030047
 tx_unicast_bytes_ok: 921153721024891
 tx_multicast_bytes_ok: 868
 tx_broadcast_bytes_ok: 4288
 tx_drops: 0
 tx_errors: 0
 tx_tso: 147060374896
 rx_frames_ok: 945863920948
 rx_frames_total: 946625249253
 rx_unicast_frames_ok: 946623896815
 rx_multicast_frames_ok: 11
 rx_broadcast_frames_ok: 1352427
 rx_bytes_ok: 617220927332403
 rx_unicast_bytes_ok: 617453019308584
 rx_multicast_bytes_ok: 1006
 rx_broadcast_bytes_ok: 86648192
 rx_drop: 0
 rx_no_bufs: 761328305
 rx_errors: 0
 rx_rss: 0
 rx_crc_errors: 0
 rx_frames_64: 7771228440
 rx_frames_127: 609137402623
 rx_frames_255: 153476479280
 rx_frames_511: 56641135859
 rx_frames_1023: 64839335794
 rx_frames_1518: 490685265
 rx_frames_to_max: 54268981993

nfsstat -o all
Server packet stats:
packets    udp        tcp        tcpconn
2740643409   1180       2740494779   1113812 

Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badclnt    badauth    xdrcall
2740451952   1701       1141       560        0       

Server reply cache:
hits       misses     nocache
185594     1806160969   934275416

Server file handle cache:
lookup     anon       ncachedir  ncachedir  stale
0          0          0          0          321859  

Server nfs v3:
null         getattr      setattr      lookup       access       readlink     
8802      0% 18074261  0% 787773    0% 1255878   0% 10635785  0% 10426     0% 
read         write        create       mkdir        symlink      mknod        
866194719 31% 1802944793 66% 189292    0% 60196     0% 2035      0% 0         0% 
remove       rmdir        rename       link         readdir      readdirplus  
201351    0% 73802     0% 5602      0% 7         0% 238       0% 2409689   0% 
fsstat       fsinfo       pathconf     commit       
16534863  0% 2446      0% 1221      0% 1928896   0% 

Server nfs v4:
null         compound     
25        0% 18886392 99% 

Server nfs v4 operations:
op0-unused   op1-unused   op2-future   access       close        commit       
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 108199    0% 32860     0% 15836     0% 
create       delegpurge   delegreturn  getattr      getfh        link         
1063      0% 0         0% 0         0% 17273601 43% 51634     0% 0         0% 
lock         lockt        locku        lookup       lookup_root  nverify      
26        0% 0         0% 26        0% 44202     0% 0         0% 0         0% 
open         openattr     open_conf    open_dgrd    putfh        putpubfh     
38101     0% 0         0% 30        0% 27        0% 18572115 47% 0         0% 
putrootfh    read         readdir      readlink     remove       rename       
23        0% 1018545   2% 48615     0% 15        0% 140807    0% 21397     0% 
renew        restorefh    savefh       secinfo      setattr      setcltid     
334450    0% 0         0% 21399     0% 11        0% 43468     0% 31        0% 
setcltidconf verify       write        rellockowner bc_ctl       bind_conn    
31        0% 0         0% 1739003   4% 25        0% 0         0% 0         0% 
exchange_id  create_ses   destroy_ses  free_stateid getdirdeleg  getdevinfo   
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 
getdevlist   layoutcommit layoutget    layoutreturn secinfononam sequence     
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 
set_ssv      test_stateid want_deleg   destroy_clid reclaim_comp 
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0%
```

NFS client

```
 nfsstat
Client rpc stats:
calls      retrans    authrefrsh
1187938914   59869      1188488980
```

Comment: High retrans rate in your `nfsstat` suggests not enough kernel threads available to handle NFS requests.  Try setting `RPCNFSDCOUNT` higher in the approriate config file for your OS.

Comment: @MikeA I believe default is 8. It is currently on 128.

Comment: @MikeA oh, unless you mean on the clients?